# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /dirección del alojamiento del proyecto/correo/PHPMailer.php on line 167

Tags: javascript, phpmailer

My problem is the following, I have a system in which I need to send emails automatically when users register in the system, in the local mode it works wonderfully and if the sending of emails is done, but when the project is hosted on the server, the Parse error appears: syntax error,   unexpected '[' in /home/www/host/scrae/correo/PHPMailer.php on line 167, I clarify that I have not moved anything in the bookstore. My code:
`

```
<?php
session_start();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'correo/Exception.php';
require 'correo/PHPMailer.php';
require 'correo/SMTP.php';
include 'model.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Ojinaga');
$fecha=date("y-m-d");
$hora=date("h:i:s");
$AdminName=$_POST['AdminName'];
  $AdminLastName=$_POST['AdminLastName'];
  $AdminMail=$_POST['AdminMail'];

  function getBaseUrl() {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $scriptName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    
    // Encuentra la posición de la última barra "/" en el nombre del script
    $lastSlash = strrpos($scriptName, '/');
    
    // Elimina el nombre del archivo de la URL y agrega una barra "/"
    $baseUrl = str_replace(substr($scriptName, $lastSlash), '/', $protocol . $host . $scriptName);

    return $baseUrl;
    
}
$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
        $mail->Username   = 'example@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxxx';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    
    
       //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'ALTA DE USUARIO');/// headers
        $mail->addAddress($AdminMail);     //Add a recipient
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Hola'." ".$AdminMail;
        $mail->Body    = '
        Estimado (a)'." ".'<b>'.$AdminName." ".$AdminLastName .'</b>'.',<br>
    
        Nos complace informarle que ha sido dado de alta exitosamente en el sistema de control de asistencia escolar del C.B.T.i.s. No. 187. Queremos darle la mas cordial bienvenida a nuestra comunidad educativa.<br>
        
        El sistema de control de asistencia escolar es una herramienta fundamental para asegurar el seguimiento del alumnado. A traves de esta plataforma, usted desempeñara el papel de administrador de esta plataforma.<br>

        A continuacion, te proporcionamos los detalles de su cuenta:<br>
        <br>
        <b>Cuenta de usuario:</b>'." ".$AdminMail.'<br>
        <b>Contrasena:</b> xxxxxxxx<br>
        <br>
        Para acceder al sistema puede hacerlo a traves de la siguiente URL <a href="'.$baseUrl.'" class="text-reset">'.$baseUrl.'</a>
        <br>
        Le recomendamos que cambie su contrasena al iniciar sesion por primera vez para garantizar la seguridad de su cuenta. Si tiene alguna dificultad para acceder al sistema o alguna pregunta relacionada, no dude en contactarnos. Estaremos encantados de ayudarte en todo lo que necesites.<br>

        Estamos emocionados de tener la oportunidad de estar en tu camino educativo en el C.B.T.i.s. No. 187. Esperamos que esta herramienta sea de gran utilidad para tu desarrollo academico y personal.<br>

        ¡Una vez mas, bienvenido(a) al sistema de control de asistencia escolar del C.B.T.i.s. No. 187!<br>
        Atentamente,<br>
        <br>
        <b></b><br>
        <b></b><br>
        <b></b><br>
        <b></b><br>
        <b></b><br>
        ';
    
        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

`

The way I work it is without the use of the vendor folder that is installed with Composer, I don't know if that's why

Comment: The error is in PHPMailer.php in line 167. You are showing something else. My guts tell me, however, that you are using an old version of PHP (on your server at least) but a new version of PHPMailer.php that expects some newer PHP features to be available and hence it doesn't work.

Comment: @CerezaDT With the screenshots provided by the host manager, in the phpMyAdmin section it is that the php version is 7.0.33

Comment: I think @CherryDT is right. This error is most likely due to the use of short array syntax that was introduced in PHP 5.4. I wouldn't necessarily assume that what's running your phpMyAdmin is the same version that's running your script (and 7.0 is also obsolete anyway), so run another script in the same folder that just contains `<?php phpinfo();` to be absolutely sure. Or alternatively run a script that just contains `<?php $a = [];` and see if it throws the same error.

Comment: @Sincro Migrate to phpmailer version 5.2 and now the following happens: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)

Comment: That's an unrelated question then, telling you your credentials are wrong or you are not allowed to connect with an external client. Note that for GMail you can't simply use your password, it's more complicated. You need to create an app password as described here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833